# Moving a Neural Network to the SQL in R

Tags: neural-network, r, sql

**tl;dr**
How do I use something like the tidypredict tool to move a neural network either textbook mlp, or deep, to SQL code?

**Background:**
This is an example that shows how to convert a linear model to SQL using tidypredict.

link:
https://tidypredict.tidymodels.org/reference/tidypredict_sql.html

Code:

```
library(dbplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: ‘dbplyr’
#> The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
#> 
#>     ident, sql

model <- lm(mpg ~ wt + am + cyl, data = mtcars)
tidypredict_sql(model, simulate_dbi())
#> <SQL> 39.4179334351865 + (`wt` * -3.12514220026708) + (`am` * 0.176493157719668) + (`cyl` * -1.5102456624971)
```

Here is how to do the same for a randomforest:

link:
https://tidypredict.netlify.app/articles/randomforest/

code:

```
library(randomForest)
model <- randomForest(Species ~ .,data = iris ,ntree = 10, proximity = TRUE)

library(tidypredict)

tidypredict_sql(model, dbplyr::simulate_mssql())
```

Part of the backend is the dbplyr interface, and the "translate_sql" function.
https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation-function.html

**Question**:
How do I get this to work with a multilayer perceptron (dense) network?  With a convolutional network?

**Thoughts:**

An old-school MLP neural network is an ensemble of parallel and series linear models with a nonlinear activation function, the nugget of which which is very clearly in-domain for tidymodels.  The process of rolling over a standard format seems like it would be the only (?) gap.

Tensorflow converts the expressions into a graph formulation, then compiles on the graph to get a sizeable speedup.  Part of that is the graph that, in theory, should be able to be translated to something like neo4j, a graph database.  TF exports to SavedModel and TensorFlow Lite formats which allow transport, and might allow translation.

H2O.ai has POJO/MOJO formats that allow model transport and deployment including for neural networks.

CRAN has a "model deployment" but it doesn't seem to give a way to encode a NN into SQL.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ModelDeployment.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720498/convert-keras-model-to-c